# React components missing after deploying MERN app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

I deployed a MERN app to Heroku (using MongoDB Atlas for database) and the home page is not rendering the login or register forms. I checked the Heroku logs for any errors and there are no errors. Also, when I inspect the elements I see the elements are there but the React components are not rendering. Only the CSS background image is rendering. Is there something off with my heroku-postbuild script? Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvK3B.png)

Heroku app hosted at "https://glacial-gorge-15530.herokuapp.com/login". Below are my server.js and package.json files. I also added images of development vs production screenshots of the login page.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

//Connect Database
connectDB();

//Init middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

//Define routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/recipes', require('./routes/recipes'));

//Serve static assets in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    //Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client', 'build', 'index.html')));
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "favorite-recipes-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "client": "0.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "create-react-app": "^3.4.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.20",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

[Screenshots of login page in production environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvK3B.png)
[Screenshots of login page in development environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebEj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.form-container` element has an opacity of `1%`, which is why the elements are invisible.

```
.form-container {
    background-color: #e7e3e3;
    opacity: 1%;
}
```

Remove `opacity: 1%`.

Comment: It looks like you may be correct. However, my CSS file has opacity at 91%. Do you know of any reason why it would convert to 1% when I deployed it?

.form-container {
  background-color: rgb(231, 227, 227);
  opacity: 91%;
}

Comment: Try `opacity: 0.91;`

Comment: I'm going to actually stick with removing the opacity all together. I think it looks better anyway. Thanks!